# C++/CLI Interface is not visible from my C# Class

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

**I have an interface in C++/CLI I need to implement in C#, but I it is not visible.** However I have other classes (abstract and concrete that I can inherit from).

My C++/CLI Interface:

```
namespace MyNamespace { namespace MySubnamespace { 

public interface class ITestInterface
{
public:
    property bool FirstProperty
    {
        bool get();
    }

    property bool SecondProperty
    {
        bool get();
    }

};

}}
```

I have a Test project where I use all the functionality in my Managed Library, but the Interface never becomes visible.

How I try to use it in my C# Test project: (I tried using it from a Class Library Project also, and it doesn't work either).

```
public class Test: MyNamespace.MySubnamespace.ITestInterface
{

}
```

I get "**Cannot resolve symbol 'ITestInterface'**"

What am I missing?

**Update**

I kept trying different things following the comments to my question, and I found that if I include my .h file in some other .h file of my C++/CLI project, the class becomes visible.
Basically I just do:

```
#include "ITestInterface.h"
```

In one of my other .h files of the C++/CLI project and the Class becomes visible to the c# project.

**Is there a way I could avoid doing that?**

Comment: A reference, most likely.  In your c# project, add a reference to your c++ class library.

Comment: @Duncan I have the reference already, that is why I can see other classes on the same library, even abstract classes, but the interface is not visible.

Comment: Well the code is not wrong.  Are you referencing a VS project, or a compiled build of the library?  And if it's the latter, are you sure it's up to date?

Comment: @Duncan Matter of fact I have both. I have a project making reference directly to my C++/CLI project. And I have another solution where I reference the dlls. To make sure the dlls were being updated I copied them manually. In both cases the Interface is not visible. Is there anything else I should take into consideration? I don't have an implementation of my interface in the C++/CLI project, could this be the reason? I only have the .h file with the code I posted.

Comment: Put `#error okay` in the .h file so you at least know for a fact that the .h file is getting #included.

Comment: @HansPassant I am not sure how to use your recommendation about "#error okay". However I tried including the .h file in another of my .h files, and now the class is visible from my c# Project. Why is that? Is there a way that I don't have to do that?

Comment: I think he's thinking that your client project is also C++, not C#.  And you don't need an implementation.  Try this: double-click the _reference_ in your C# project to open the object browser.  Open the node for the client library and make sure you see the interface, and that the namespace/names are correct.  I tried it with your code and it works fine.

Comment: You don't mention where your `ITestInterface` is declared, but it *must* at some point be included by a cpp file that will be compiled as part of the project. If you don't need to include this for use in other parts of the interface, just put it in a cpp file instead of a header.

Comment: @Duncan I did what you told me, and in the object browser I can see my Interface, but I can still not use it. I think my problem is related with crashmstr post.

Comment: @crashmstr I understand what you mean, I haven't thought about it since I was thinking this is .Net If you post that as the answer I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++/CLI is similar to C++ in that only .cpp files are compiled directly. Header files are only compiled when included. This is why adding an `#include` for your interface header works.

There are several ways to make sure your code is included for a C++/CLI class:

- Have both a .h and .cpp file (even if the .cpp file only includes the .h file it corresponds to)
- Have only include files and then include all of the headers in one .cpp file (which may be empty other than the includes)
- Have only .cpp files (which is fine if the other code does not reference this code)